# Jackson InvalidDefinitionException while serializing

Tags: java, jackson

as I said in the title im trying to serialize a very very simple object but that gives a lot of problems. Im gonna post code and errors (very simple and short).

```
package assignment6;

public class Transaction {

private String date;
private String causal;

public Transaction() {}

public String getDate() { return this.date; }

public String getCausal() { return this.causal; }

public void setDate(String date) { this.date = date; }

public void setCausal(String causal) { this.causal = causal; }

}


package assignment6;

import java.io.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Transaction t = new Transaction();
        t.setDate("07/11/2020");
        t.setCausal("pagobancomat");
        File f = new File("try.json");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            om.writeValue(f, t);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `assignment6.Transaction`: Failed to construct BeanSerializer for [simple type, class assignment6.Transaction]: (java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException) Unable to make public java.lang.String assignment6.Transaction.getDate() accessible: module reti does not "exports assignment6" to module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:72)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadTypeDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1163)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:438)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:279)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:231)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1388)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1336)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:510)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:713)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.9.7/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3159)
> at reti/assignment6.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:26)

Im so done.. don't know how to resolve this problem, any tips?
UP 1

Comment: There's a typo in `Transaction` class definition, remove the parentheses after class name: `public class Transaction {...}`

Comment: that's a missclick, sorry. That's not present in the original code

Comment: Without that typo the code compiles and succeeds, file `try.json` is generated successfully: `{"date":"07/11/2020","causal":"pagobancomat"}`

Comment: When I compile it shows the errors I posted after the code. If that works on ur end doesn't mean that must work in mine..

Comment: Agree, this means that a broader context is needed

Comment: broader in which sense? I've got an error and im looking for a solution.. I can't provide you a broader context if I don't know which error this is